# Using Google Maps in a web app for iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-maps-api-3

Is there a special way to call the Google Maps API in HTML for a web app for Mobile?

I am currently calling them in the standard way.. i.e.

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" %>
lat = 53.80620266482967
lng = -3.205146811523491
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
options =
  zoom: 6

  center: latlng
  mapTypeId: 'OSM'
  panControlOptions:
     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  zoomControlOptions:
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
  mapTypeControlOptions:
    mapTypeIds: ['CloudMade', 'OSM', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
@gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)
@gMap.mapTypes.set('OSM', osmMapType)
@gMap.mapTypes.set('CloudMade', cloudMadeMapType)
@gMap.setMapTypeId(cloudMadeMapType)
```

But they seem a little slow and very jolty, not as smooth as the native app... anyone done this before. I would like to have them as smooth as possible.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference of instantiating a Google Map on a mobile device. Naturally, anything running in a browser is expected to perform less smoothly than a native app, so that's not a fair comparison. But, is your mobile map performing worse than it does when you go to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com)? Also, we don't know what your cloudMadeMapType and osmMapType are doing. Could there be some intense computation there?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter if you use the standard way, or any other way - the map will show up anyways on pretty much any device( including iPad ), but it will most likely be "jolty" and "slow". After all, you are are running it inside a web browser.

There are, however, special **jQuery** plugins that can be used for developing **Google Maps** applications for mobile devices( e.g. [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) ).

Comment: How would adding more JavaScript make it less jolty and slow? For the record, the only thing that makes it jolty and slow is poor coding, I've got a very JS-heavy google map application that runs like a dream on iPad in safari.